# How to parse below JSON response using Karate API

Tags: karate

Can anyone to how to part below response in Karate API

Here I want to extract partNumber and productTitle from the response, where initial numeric number in the response is dynamic nature, for every get method the number changes.

{"items":{'41651625424': {itemCore: {partNumber: '1234567', productTitle: 'Karate API Testing'}}}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways, but in this case, the best option to me is to use JsonPath:

```
* def response = { "items": { '41651625424': { itemCore: { partNumber: '1234567', productTitle: 'Karate API Testing' }}}}
* def itemCore = get[0] response..itemCore
* match itemCore == { partNumber: '1234567', productTitle: 'Karate API Testing' }
```

Refer to the documentation: https://github.com/intuit/karate#get-plus-index

Comment: Hi Peter, Thank you for your quick response. I am able to get partNumber and productTtile with star. But I want to retrieve 41651625424 this value in a variable as  I have to pass this as input in another request body

Comment: Hi Peter,  below statement is working fine in eclipse but not in intelliJ,                  def itemCore = get[0] response..itemCore                                                            getting java.lang.RuntimeException: javascript evaluation failed: get[0] response..itemCore

Comment: @sam the time has come for me to point you to this: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: how to get the 2nd partnumber from below response.I tried get[1] but it is printing empty.

{
    "wasAdded": true,
    "lineItems": {
        "1111111": {
            "itemCore": {
                "partNumber": "10000061"
            }
        },
         "222222": {
            "itemCore": {
                "partNumber": "10000062"
            }
        },
        "3333333": {
            "itemCore": {
                "partNumber": "10000063"
            }
        }
    }
    
}

Comment: @sam open a new question please